# Включить поддержку Filestream

Tags: sql, sql-server

Никак не могу включить поддержку  Filestream  в БД.

Выполняю инсткрукции в соотв. с http://eazybi.blogspot.com/2014/05/sql-2012-filestream-filetable.html

У меня нету  опции  FILESTREAM  на уровне службы SQL Server. Что делать? 
Возможно, я пропустил инсталяцию данного компонента при установке?

```
alter database ks
add filegroup fsGroup contains filestream;
go

alter database ks
add file
  ( NAME = 'fsYourDatabase', FILENAME = 'D:\filestream'
   )
to filegroup fsGroup;
```

Код выдаёт ошибку

> FILESTREAM feature is disabled. Msg 1921, Level 16, State 4, Line 13
>   Invalid filegroup 'fsGroup' specified.

---

В  случае

```
exec sp_configure 'filestream access level',1;
reconfigure with override

SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('FilestreamEffectiveLevel');
```

все равно выводит статус 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте версию SQL Server! Насколько я помню в Express варианте нужна версия 2008 R2 SQL Server.

Comment: Вроде filestream в 2012 появился?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
 Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Очень странно...Если не включать Filestream на этапе инсталляции самого сервера то потом через Configuration Manager это легко делается. Попробуйте поставить SP 1. Если это не поможет тогда пробовать другую инсталяху.

Comment: @Qwertiy в 2012 добавили FileTable, а FileStream был уже в 2008

Comment: Через Configuration Manager сделал ... Благодарен. Формите ответом коментарий и прийму